# UDP DNS and DHCP testing local server. Spoofing?

Tags: server, dns, dhcp, spoofing

Trying to find some kind of DNS resolver to redirect UDP based traffic from a video game trying to connect to a master server that no longer exists. It pings for the domain example: videogame.m3.publisher.com
and the domain for the video game does not exist, is there a way to spoof a domain on windows locally?

Tried to set up virtual instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 and couldn't find a way to mimic the domain/dns name properly.

What is the most ethical/safest route/educational route? Thank You!

Comment: You can edit `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and add the following line `127.0.0.1    videogame.m3.publisher.com`.

Comment: If I’m using a game console pinging from the console at 192.168.1.218 and my windows machine is at 192.168.1.223, will this work?